# Chatter : getDeleted EntitySubscription and FeedLike

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, salesforce-chatter

There are no triggers available on EntitySubscription and FeedLike objects, so there's no way available to log deletion of these objects.

Is there a way to determine the deleted entity subscription and feedlike records for a specific period of time ie say a api call that gives last xhrs deleted records.

I tried using ALL ROWS and Isdeleted=true clause with  EntitySubscription to retrieve deleted records, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via the [getDeleted](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_getdeleted.htm) call in the SOAP API, but i don't think that's exposed in apex anywhere.